# How to login to CVS with extssh

Tags: authentication, ssh, hudson, cvs

I'm trying to setup Hudson to pull from a CVS repo, and need a .cvspass file to do that, and to generate .cvspass, I need to first login manually to CVS (AFAIK).

CVS server in question only seems to support extssh, and I can't figure out how to login into it. I tried something like this:

```
robert@robert-laptop:~/temp$ cvs -d  :extssh:USERNAME:PASSWORD@cvs.server.com:/path/to/project login
cvs login: CVSROOT password specification is only valid for
cvs login: pserver connection method.
cvs [login aborted]: Bad CVSROOT: `:extssh:USERNAME:PASSWORD@cvs.server.com:/path/to/project'.
```

I tried with and without password, and all other permutations I could think of, but nothing helped. Does someone know a proper way to do it?

**UPDATE:**

I managed to login and checkout with:

```
robert@robert-laptop:~/temp$ cvs -d :extssh:USERNAME@cvs.server.com:/path/to/repo co PROJECT_NAME
```

but .cvspass was not generated, which was the whole point. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says

```
cvs login: CVSROOT password specification is only valid for
cvs login: pserver connection method.
```

Since you do not use a pserver I would try

```
cvs -d  :extssh:USERNAME@cvs.server.com:/path/to/project login
```

It might be that you can't actually use CVS to store the password. Try to set up a password-less ssh connection. see http://ant.1045680.n5.nabble.com/Authenticating-cvs-extssh-w-o-getting-prompted-td1356537.html

Comment: I am facing same problem and i am using pserver. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

From https://netpenthe.wordpress.com/2007/01/25/extssh-is-an-eclipse-only-cvs-connection-method/

> The extssh connection method is unique to Eclipse CVS and doesn’t exist in the
>   command-line CVS client. If you are using extssh to connect to a SSH2
>   repository and would like to use the command line client for some CVS
>   operations you can configure the ext connection method to use extssh when
>   inside Eclipse.

In other words... checkout the project in eclipse using the ext connection method and not extssh if you want to use the cvs command line client.